# how to delete specific user row, from a table printed from the database with jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

In my dynamic web site I'm writing the part about the administrator. He can see all registered users and can delete one or more of them. The problem is that I'm not understanding how to pass the specific users ID.

My code is:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table border="1">
        <thead><tr>
                        <th>NAME</th>
                        <th>SURNAME</th>
                        <th>USERSID</th>
                        <th>USERNAME</th>
                        <th>PASSWORD</th>
                        <th>EMAIL</th>
                        <th>ROLE</th>
                        <th>ACTIONS</th>
                    </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <% 
                Vector<String[]> risultati = AmministratoreDAO.getInstance().getListUsers();

                //prova
                String riga2 = "0";

                if(risultati.size()>0)
                {
                    for(int i=0; i<risultati.size(); i++)
                    {
                        String[] riga = risultati.get(i);
                        out.print("<tr>");


        riga2 = riga[2];
                session.setAttribute("codicefiscale", riga2);

                for(int j=0; j < riga.length; j++)
                {
                    out.append("<td>" + riga[j] + "  </td>");
                }


                out.print(" <td><a href='AdminDeleteUser.jsp'?id=+riga[2]> cancellare</a></td>"); 
            out.print("</tr>"); 
                }
            }else{
            out.print("NON CI SONO RISULTATI");
        }
            %>

        </tbody>

    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: aren't you already passing id's here? [?id=+riga[2]]

Answer (score 0):

```
out.print(" <td><a href='AdminDeleteUser.jsp'?id=+riga[2]> cancellare</a></td>"); 
==================================================================================
instead of you should write like this
out.print(" <td><a href='AdminDeleteUser.jsp?id=riga[2]'> cancellare</a></td>");
```

now to get id

```
String str=request.getParameter("id");
```

Comment: it doesn't work because when i try to delete one row of the table, the id is "riga[2]" and not the user id

Comment: ok...i thought you are storing uid in riga[2] ..but you must put uid in query string i.e.
?id=[user id] like this. if any problem then my email address is ==>12mscca19@gmail.com